# Difference between $this->config and \Drupal::config in ConfigFormBase

Tags: 8, configuration

I want to override a custom module configuration in the `settings.php` file. So the configuration in database can be independent from the environment.

```
$config['my_module.settings']['prop'] = 'foo';
```

I my module configuration form, the config result is different given the method I use to get it :

```
class MyConfigurationForm extends ConfigFormBase {

    public function buildForm( array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){
        $config = $this->config( 'my_module.settings' );
        print_r( $config->get('prop') ); 
        // prints database value, or nothing if there is no value in database for 'prop'

        $config = \Drupal::config( 'my_module.settings' );
        print_r( $config->get('prop') ); 
        // prints 'foo'
    }

}
```

Why is that ? 
What's the difference between these two methods ?

Comment: I believe because one returns an immutable object only, and the other returns a mutable or immutable object (picking up your runtime changes). https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21ConfigFormBaseTrait.php/function/ConfigFormBaseTrait%3A%3Aconfig/8.2.x vs https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Aconfig/8.2.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a configuration form use `$this->config()` and not `\Drupal::config()`.

The difference between both is that the configuration form uses immutable configuration.

When Drupal 8 was in beta, the immutable configuration was introduced to avoid bleeding of overridden values into configuration when saved to the database. See the change record:

[Configuration objects by default are immutable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407153)

This is the code executed by `$this->config()` of a configuration form, in a static version:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.site')->set('name', 'My fantastic site')->save();
```

---

For Drupal 8.7 it is discussed to display a warning for overridden values:

> This form contains values that have been overridden. Changes to these
>   values can still be saved, but the overridden values will take
>   precedence. Overrides are as follows ...

See the issue:

[There is no indication on configuration forms if there are overridden values](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408549)